# Read a json file that contains multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
{'e': 'test', 'E': 1657471446261, 's': 'asset', 'b': [['20890.93000000', '0.00000000'], ['20889.96000000', '0.00000000']], 'a': [['20888.21000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.28000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.30000000', '0.00000000']]}
{'e': 'test', 'E': 1657471446260, 's': 'asset', 'b': [['20890.93000000', '0.00000000'], ['20889.96000000', '0.00000000']], 'a': [['20888.21000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.28000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.30000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.42000000', '0.00000000']]}
```

How can I open it in a dataframe or other format in python because in any case it doesn't work.
Or load this type of json into a dataframe:

```
[
  [
    "19789.38000000",
    "0.00000000"
  ],
  [
    "19788.19000000",
    "0.00053000"
  ]
][
[
    "19789.41000000",
    "0.00000000"
  ],
  [
    "19789.05000000",
    "0.00000000"
  ],
  [
    "19788.19000000",
    "0.00000000"
]]
```

Comment: What is the desired output of your dataframe?

Comment: The data frame output does not matter too much as long as it is loaded, but preferably every entry is row and key is the column name

Comment: Is your json output above exactly how the data is formatted in the json? Because it doesn't appear to be valid. can you post the raw json?

Comment: It basically is multiple dictionaries added in a text file with:
   with open('test.json', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(json.loads(data), outfile, indent=0)

Comment: Just put each dictionary in a list, then call pd.DataFrame() on the list. If the dictionaries get stored as strings use eval(str_dict) to convert it to a python dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert dictionary with irregular index values.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'e': 'test', 'E': 1657471446261, 's': 'asset', 'b': [['20890.93000000', '0.00000000'], ['20889.96000000', '0.00000000']], 'a': [['20888.21000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.28000000', '0.00000000'], ['20888.30000000', '0.00000000']]}
df = pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in data.items() })
```

output:

```
      e             E      s                             b                             a
0  test  1.657471e+12  asset  [20890.93000000, 0.00000000]  [20888.21000000, 0.00000000]
1   NaN           NaN    NaN  [20889.96000000, 0.00000000]  [20888.28000000, 0.00000000]
2   NaN           NaN    NaN                           NaN  [20888.30000000, 0.00000000]
```

I hope you are expecting for this.